# SVG is scaled non-uniformly in Firefox using <img> tag

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I have the following SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="100%" height="19">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <text font-size="13" font-family="monospace" x="3" y="13" fill="#b2b2b2">Hello world</text>
</svg>
```

If I view that file directly in Firefox, it looks fine:

[image: Good-looking screenshot]

If I include it in a page using an `<img>` tag, however, it appears squished.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="screenshot.svg" width="100%">
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Bad-looking screenshot]

What I would like to happen is for the black background to scale to cover the entire width while the text remains unsquished.  I've tried all the permutations of `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` I can think of but none of them seem to have the desired effect.  Chrome seems to display it fine.

Comment: What happens if you use `px` units instead of `pt`?

Comment: @ccprog Good question, it doesn't seem to have any effect though.  I converted everything to pixels to simplify the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect (both on Windows/63 and Linux/60esr), but I can see minimal differences in the antialiasing computation on Windows, depending on the font used. What font does the browser use?

Comment: Here's an interesting observation: If I use <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> to enlarge the display on screen, scaling is uneven between width and height. Are you using a high-density screen so px values get pre-multiplied?

Comment: @ccprog Yes, I do have a high DPI screen

Comment: Don't forget to remove margin from the html body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, in my opinion, should be labeled as a bug. What seems to happen is that, either on usage of the browser zoom function, or on a predefined zoom due to a high DPI screen, a percentage or viewport-relative (vw, vh) value stays at the same computed pixel size, while px and other unit values get multiplied with the zoom value. So far, so fine.

It seems that in Firefox for `<img>` witdth and height values this always results in an uneven scaling of its content, not preserving the aspect ratio, even for SVG content that normally would fit itself in a viewport according to the `preserveAspectRatio` rules.

I see two ways around that; both need to explicitely set the height. Please note that I have tested that on a regular screen by using the browser zoom function. I hope it works the same on your high DPI screen.

- embed the SVG image in the HTML page by using an inline `<svg>` tag containing a SVG `<image>` element:

  ```
  <html>
    <body style="margin:0">
      <svg width="100%" height="19px">
        <image width="100%" height="100%" href="screenshot.svg" />
      </svg>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- use the SVG as a background image:

  ```
  <html>
    <body style="margin:0">
      <div style="background:url(screenshot.svg) left no-repeat;width:100%;height:19px;">
    </body>
  </html>
  ```